# What Binding of Isaac Item Gives This Mask

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I was playing as Azazel and I noticed that when I stand still a white mask appears on my face.
If anyone could direct me to the wiki-page of this item, or effect, it would be greatly appreciated

1. These are all my items:
   [image: Picture 1]
2. This is what the mask looks like:
   [image: Picture 2]
3. And this is what I look like moving/just coming to a stop:
   [image: Picture 3]

Comment: Seed is 319S Z4HL, if anyones interested

Comment: PS4 or PC? Seeds aren't the same across platforms

Comment: PC (mac to be specific) I didn't realize it was for PS4 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the second screenshot, your "mask" is due to the [Gnawed Leaf](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Gnawed_Leaf), as you can see this is the appearence:

[image]

That's the fifth item in your first screenshot.

This item is a reference to the "Tanuki suit" from Super Mario Bros 3, which also has a similar tail and the ability to turn into a statue.

Comment: So this means i've basically broken the game, as i can stay still and have my circle of laser deal damage... :D

Comment: GG xD which item makes your Brimstone do a circle? Uhm, I guess it's the The Ludovico Technique.

Comment: Yep! I forget what made the laser wide, but this just goes further to prove his even stats *cough*

Comment: Best combo ever.

Comment: @Jordan.McBride Yes. You can't move the laser and remain invincible but you can just leave it there and wait for them to run into it.

Answer (score 3):

The item doing this was the [Gnawed Leaf](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Gnawed_Leaf).

The Gnawed Leaf caused Isaac to turn to stone and become immune to all damage if he stays still and doesn't fire or use bombs/items for a second. The "white mask" was this effect.